# appengine dev_appserver time strangeness

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm new to Google AppEngine & to Go & to Web stacks - so it is very likely something I'm doing wrong here, but I can't figure it out :)

I'm trying to write a simple clock app in Go where the the server pushes to the client & a JS handler updates an HTML element.  I'm using the TaskQueue api to reschedule the server side update, and I've changed the default queue frequency to be once per second.  The server sends a payload string that contains the number of times the task URL has been hit & the current time.  The hit count updates at a rate of 1 per second, as expected - but the time stamp barely changes.  The log output I'm seeing in the dev_appserver console looks correct

```
INFO     2012-07-05 03:04:31,955 dev_appserver.py:2952] "POST /update HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-07-05 03:04:31,985 dev_appserver.py:2952] "POST /update HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-07-05 03:04:32,015 dev_appserver.py:2952] "POST /update HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-07-05 03:04:32,043 dev_appserver.py:2952] "POST /update HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I've pasted my code below (is a pastebin better?).

Cheers!
Brad

```
package clock

import (
    "fmt"
    "appengine"
    "appengine/channel"
    "appengine/datastore"
    "appengine/taskqueue"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "time"
//  "appengine/user"
)

type Greeting struct {
    Author  string
    Content string
    Date    time.Time
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", root)
    http.HandleFunc("/update", update)
}

type TemplateFiller struct {
    Time      string
    Token     string
}

var clientId string = "clockclient"

func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    q := datastore.NewQuery("Greeting").Order("-Date").Limit(10)
    greetings := make([]Greeting, 0, 10)
    if _, err := q.GetAll(c, &greetings); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    token, _ := channel.Create(c, clientId);
    tf := TemplateFiller{time.Now().String(), token}

    if err := guestbookTemplate.Execute(w, tf); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    reschedule(c)
}

func reschedule(c appengine.Context) {
    t := taskqueue.NewPOSTTask("/update", map[string][]string{"token": {clientId}})
        if _, err := taskqueue.Add(c, t, ""); err != nil {
            return
        }
}

var hits int = 0

func update(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    channel.Send(c, clientId, fmt.Sprintln(hits) + time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
    hits = hits + 1
    //channel.Send(c, clientId, time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
    reschedule(c)
}

var guestbookTemplate = template.Must(template.New("").Parse(guestbookTemplateHTML))

const guestbookTemplateHTML = `
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
<div id="timediv">No time</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   onMessage = function(msg) {
      $("#timediv").html(msg.data);
   }

    channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('{{.Token}}');
    socket = channel.open();
    //socket.onopen = onOpened;
    socket.onmessage = onMessage;
    //socket.onerror = onError;
    //socket.onclose = onClose;
 });

</script>

  </body>
</html>
`
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The dev_server queue and timing behaves nothing like how the production server behaves (timing wise).
2. It is a very bad idea to depend on the queue to give you a constat and stable timer interup.

Comment: Thanks for a response!  1. I'm using time.Now().String() to get the time, surely the server's timestamp is coming from the OS & should be correctish.  2. I'm not really expecting the Task queue to provide more than a periodic update.  Not really intending to use this sort of thing in production, but my first test app showed some very odd behaviour.